# Error running tests - jest.mock is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, codesandbox

I am trying to run tests using Jest, however I am getting this error:

> jest.mock is not a function

What am I doing wrong? Here's my CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/polling-hook-demo-9yo8c

Note that I am configuring Jest inside my package.json:

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
  "./src/test/setupTestsAfterEnv.ts"
]
```

setupTestsAfterEnv.ts extends Jest expect using jest-dom:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

I am also using react-testing-library.

**Update**

This appears to be an issue with my CodeSandbox configuration. I tried the same thing with create-react-app locally and the problem went away!

Here's my Github repo where Jest runs perfectly well: https://github.com/nareshbhatia/hooked-on-polling.

I then imported this repo in a new CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hooked-on-polling-2em7g. When I run tests in this sandbox, I again get the same error: *jest.mock is not a function*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed that this is an issue with CodeSandbox: https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/513

Comment: Still an issue 29 April 2022